# mark read unread messages (jsp pages)

Tags: jsp, read-unread

i have a system (developed in java) who generates messages to the user. I want to display theses messages to the user. Their initial state will be "unread" and then when the user read them, the messages become "read". Also the user will be able to delete the messages
how can this be done?
The messages will be shown to the user as checkboxes, in order to choose which one he wants to delete after he reads them(another idea?)
Also i am not sure yet how i will get the messages (maybe in Map?)
Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is nothing but changing the status in table for that message.

When User does any read, delete operation, you can make an ajax call (So that things will go smooth and no waiting for server interactions for changing status) based on some parameter.

At server side write one function which based on parameter, either change message status to modify/delete/unread/read in you table. JSP will simply read the status and act accordingly.